# InStr Function Not Working

Tags: vba, excel, module

Essentially I have a loop where on the ***eighth*** loop of the program, I want the program to see if a certain cell contains the string "Y". If it contains Y, it should go to the allocated cell and mark "X", if it does not, it should go to the adjacent cell and mark "X".
However, no matter how I set up the InStr function, it always return marks the string as not found and marks it in the not found cell. This is regardless of whether or not there is a "Y"
Can someone point me in the correct direction?

```
For i = 1 To 10
    If i = 1 Then
        rng1.Copy Destination:=rng2

    ElseIf i = 2 Then
        rng1.Offset(0, 1).Copy Destination:=rng2.Offset(0, 1)

    ElseIf i = 3 Then
        rng1.Offset(0, 2).Copy Destination:=rng2.Offset(0, 2)

    ElseIf i = 4 Then
        rng1.Offset(0, 3).Copy Destination:=rng2.Offset(0, 3)

    ElseIf i = 5 Then
        rng1.Offset(0, 4).Copy Destination:=rng2.Offset(0, 4)

    ElseIf i = 6 Then
        rng1.Offset(0, 5).Copy Destination:=rng2.Offset(0, 5)

    ElseIf i = 7 Then
        rng1.Offset(0, 6).Copy Destination:=rng2.Offset(0, 6)

    ElseIf i = 8 Then
        If InStr(1, cellText, "Y", 1) > 0 Then  '<~Problem here
            rng2.Offset(0, 7).Value = "X"
        Else
            rng2.Offset(0, 8).Value = "X"
        End If

    ElseIf i = 9 Then
        rng1.Offset(0, 10).Copy Destination:=rng2.Offset(0, 9)

    Else
        rng1.Offset(0, 11).Copy Destination:=rng2.Offset(0, 10)

    End If
    Next i
```

Comment: It might help to see how you assign a value to `cellText`.

Comment: Can you print out the value of cellText in the debug window?

Comment: cellText = rng1.Offset(0, 10).Text

Comment: I have checked and double checked that the value on it is "Y"

Comment: So if you put `Debug.Print cellText` immediately before the `InStr` line, you see `Y` in the immediate window? BTW you could condense the code a fair bit with a `Select Case i` statement.

Comment: I tried 'Debug.Print cellText' and nothing happened

Comment: How does 'Select Case i' statement work?

Comment: If you didn't see anything in the Immediate Window in the VB Editor, then there is nothing in the `cellText` variable.

Comment: Does 'cellText = mg1.Offset(0, 10).Text' retrieve the text in that specific cell block and store it into the string **cellText**?

Comment: Yes it does. What do you see with the `MsgBox` line I put in my answer?

Comment: You were correct, 'cellText' did not retrieve the correct information. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't directly addressing your main question, but a demonstration of how to use `Select Case` to shorten your code (and also adds a message box to check your `cellText` variable):

```
For i = 1 To 10
    Select Case i
        Case 1 To 7
            rng1.Offset(0, i - 1).Copy Destination:=rng2.Offset(0, i - 1)
        Case 8
            MsgBox cellText
            If InStr(1, cellText, "Y", 1) > 0 Then  '<~Problem here
                rng2.Offset(0, 7).Value = "X"
            Else
                rng2.Offset(0, 8).Value = "X"
            End If

        Case 9 To 10
            rng1.Offset(0, i + 1).Copy Destination:=rng2.Offset(0, i + 1)

    End Select
Next i
```

Comment: Okay I understand how that works now, thank you so much!